# Question having limits,summation,definite integral all together

Tags: limits, definite-integrals

Let $L=\lim_{n\to \infty}n.\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left[\int_\limits{\frac{k}{n}}^{\frac{k+1}{n}}\sqrt{\left(x-\frac{k}{n}\right)\left(\frac{k+1}{n}-x\right)}dx\right]$,then find the value of $\frac{1000L}{\pi}$

It seems to be double integral question,I could not solve it.Hints and suggestions are expected.Thanks

Comment: Let $y = x - \frac{k}{n} = \frac1n t$, the $k^{th}$ integral $= \int_0^{1/n} \sqrt{y\left(\frac1n - y\right)} dx
= \frac{1}{n^2}\int_0^1 \sqrt{t(1-t)} dt$

Comment: @achillehui,$k^{th} $integral is $\frac{\pi}{8}$,does that mean $L=\frac{\pi}{8}?$

Comment: The $k^{th}$ integral is $\frac{\pi}{8n^2}$ but yes, $L  = \frac{\pi}{8}$.

Comment: @achillehui,how did that happen?

Comment: $L  = \lim_{n\to\infty} n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{\pi}{8n^2} = \lim_{n\to\infty} n^2\frac{\pi}{8n^2}$

Comment: @achillehui,got it.Thank you so much.If u had written in answer,i would have +1 ed it.